# Only one line (the last) in a for loop is plotting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, line

I am trying to plot horizontal lines through each of 6 blots in a western blot image (molecular biology type stuff).  For some reason, I can only get the line to be drawn through the last blot, at the end of the loop.  Thoughts?[western_blot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwlbN.png)

```
clear;
clc;

my_image = imread('acetylation.tif');

for i = 1:6

[x_coord, y_coord, intensities]=impixel(my_image);  
avg_y = (sum(y_coord))/2;

imshow(my_image);
line([x_coord(1,:),x_coord(2,:)],[avg_y,avg_y], 'Color', 'white')
hold on;

end
```

Comment: You don't reference `i` anywhere in the loop, so it's just doing exactly the same thing (i.e. plotting the same line) 6 times over.
That said, it's poor form to post an example that we can't run

Comment: Maybe it should be `[x_coord (1,i),x_coord (2,i)]` ?

Comment: Take out imshow out of the loop, it covers the previous plotted data in each iteration

Answer (score 0):

The function [`impixel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixel.html) is going to keep overwriting your image when it creates a new figure for you to select points within. Therefore, you should instead be collecting your points in a loop using [`impixel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixel.html), storing the data, then making your plot afterward. Try this:

```
x_coord = [];
y_coord = [];

for i = 1:6
  [x_coord(:, i), y, intensities] = impixel(my_image);
  avg_y = (sum(y))/2;
  y_coord(:, i) = [avg_y; avg_y];
end

imshow(my_image);
line(x_coord, y_coord, 'Color', 'white');
```